# Jquery-Mobile: How to deploy the sample application into the device

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile framework. I implemented the sample application using jquery mobile.Now i want to deploy this application into device. I don't know how to deploy this? please can anybody help me.

```
    Sample Application
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page< /title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>My Title</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">   
            <p>Hello world</p>      
        </div><!-- /content -->    
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>End of the page</h1>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: What kind of application is that..?

Comment: i updated my app code above. please tell me the procedure to install this in device(like android,iphone..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery mobile only provides you with tools for mobile UI (mostly, touch-oriented). It is used with normal web application backend to make mobile view (presentation), based on user agent, for example. Such applications are deployed on web-server. If you want to make device-deployable application - use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) or something like that.

Comment: can u suggest which is the best for deploying?(phonegap or anything else).

Answer (score 6):

Jquery is a framework which makes your life simpler in modifying the content through its
funcitons,selectors.Instead of writing huge lines of javascript You can make your life simpler with Jquery.

In order to check your result of your code.

You can use phonegap .

Install the phonegap plugin with eclipse.
Create an new project through phone gap.
Paste your code in index.html.
Then  build the code as per your choice of mobile platform.
Then u can debug/run the code through android simulators or deploy it on the phone.

Comment: it means use the jquery mobile code in the index.html of phone gap application and then build the code for ur mobile choice right(means android,iphone..)?

Comment: No, you write an application with PhoneGap JS APIs. You do not need to use jQuery at all (but you can). Then you build it, and PhonGap translates JS calls to native ones.

Comment: i am confusing with this please can you give the sample application

Comment: Look at their wiki: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494764/PhoneGap%20Geolocation%20Sample%20Application

Comment: Phone gap uses jquery html css javascript to build the applications as u have written the code in jquery and if u want to see it executable then u use Phonegap.